# Are there drawbacks to leaving a SqlConnection open long-term?

Tags: windows, service, ado.net, sqlconnection

I am creating a MS Windows service, which listens for TCP connections. When connected, it gets data from a SQL db and returns it via the TCP socket. What are the drawbacks, if any, of opening a `SqlConnection` to the SQL Server at service start time, and just re-using that, until it might fail, as opposed to opening a new connection each time a "request" is made?  I expect a small number of instantiations of the service functionality - less than 10 a day, but it could be more than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database connections are considered an "expensive" resource, and as such should be opened only when needed, and closed immediately thereafter. As a result, opening a connection early and persisting it would go against that philosophy. Additionally, doing so prevents your underlying framework from making best use of whatever variety of connection pooling it may implement. It just isn't a very scalable practice.

Comment: Thanks that's helpful. Why are db connections considered "expensive"?

Comment: Well, if you consider the possibility that a server may open multiple connections to the same database for entirely different applications, yours might not be the only one talking to it. Also, the kind of data being sent across that connection might require a great deal of bandwidth and/or CPU time, implying overhead just to keep a connection open even if at a given time it isn't being used.